# Setting up PHP SDK for Couchbase on Windows?

Tags: php, couchbase

Can anyone please help me out with step by step setting up of PHP SDK for Couchbase on Windows and running a simple PHP file using Couchbase. I tried running the following PHP program and have already followed the instructions given in this blog (http://trondn.blogspot.no/2013/04/couchbase-php-xampp-and-windows.html)

PHP file:

```
<?php
// Connect to Couchbase Server
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket('beer-sample');
// Retrieve a document
$result = $bucket->get('aass_brewery-juleol');
$doc = $result->value;
echo $doc->name . ', ABV: ' . $doc->abv . "\n";
// Store a document
$doc->comment = 'Random beer from Norway';
$result = $bucket->replace('aass_brewery-juleol', $doc);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

I keep getting the error: 
**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseException' with message 'The key does not exist on the server' in [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php:196 Stack trace: #0 [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php(196): _CouchbaseBucket->get('aass_brewery-ju...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hello-couchbase.php(9): CouchbaseBucket->get('aass_brewery-ju...') #2 {main} thrown in [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php on line 196**

I have couchbase installed and a sample bucket - 'beer-sample' installed

Answer (score 0):

Don't use accounts with admin permissions to perform data transactions. Either pass NULL as the username or name of the bucket. Here's a sample code.

```
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "beer-sample");
$cb->set("foo", "bar");
var_dump("foo");
```